# $digest isn't being called enough to trigger $watch - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a `$watch` function that centers an element vertically because I don't always know the height and width of an element. 
The function works if I have `$timeout` in my directive before the `$watch` function, so that `$digest` is called enough times for my `$watch` function to be called when the height or width of my element changes when the page finally loads.
However, if I remove `$timeout` from the directive, `$watch` is often not called because the `$digest` cycle didn't happen when the height or width of the element changed.
Using `$timeout` this often causes the error: `"10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"`

Does anyone know of another way to trigger the `$digest` cycle without constantly using `$timeout`?  Or is there a way I can edit my `$watch` function so that it'll function properly?  Or is there something I can tag onto my element so it triggers a `$digest` cycle when it loads?

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('task2')
.directive('centerVertical', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            $timeout();
            return { 
                'h': element[0].offsetHeight
            };
        }, 
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var elementHeight = newValue.h;

            /*To account for rounding errors and not loop*/
            if(elementHeight % 2 === 0)
            {
                element.css('margin-top', '-' + ((elementHeight) / 2) + 'px');
            }
            else 
            {
                element.css('margin-top', '-' + ((elementHeight + 1) / 2) + 'px');
            }
        }, true);

        element.bind('centerVertical', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to not use `$watch` at all, and to update the height once the DOM loads.  It was very simple, and I feel silly for not seeing this before.  I hope this helps someone before they spend hours trying to do something really complicated like I tried.

```
angular.module('task2')
.directive('centerElement', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            element.css('margin-top', '-' + (element[0].offsetHeight / 2) + 'px');
            element.css('margin-left', '-' + (element[0].offsetWidth / 2) + 'px');
        });
    };
});
```